# Find nested related users

Tags: postgresql, query

From this SQL schemas, I want to find all users related by contest.id

[image]

**I try this req :**

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.avatar FROM contests c
LEFT JOIN trials AS t ON (t.contest_id = c.id)
LEFT JOIN trials_has_users AS tu ON (tu.trial_id = t.id)
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (u.id = tu.trial_id)
WHERE c.id = '7a101d23-a1d5-457c-821e-14321ae3bb64'
GROUP BY u.id;
```

but it does not work, `u.id`, `u.firstname`, `u.lastname`, `u.avatar` is `NULL`, and I only have one result

Comment: Please provide CREATE TABLE for tables (excess columns may be skipped), INSERT INTO with some sample data (3-5 rows per table) and desired output for this data. Or create online fiddle.

Comment: Hello @Akina I a write this:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7ccb30/1 
with my sqlfiddle example that works 